# duplicates from the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

"Can you help me with these points below...

1. Please split and store all the words from the file into an ArrayList. Print the contents of the ArrayList.
2. Using the ArrayList created in previous question, please create a new ArrayList that contains only unique words in the book (get rid of all the duplicates from the ArrayList). For simplicity, please ignore case differences (upper vs. lower case) and punctuation marks.
3. Please print a list of all the words used in the file (christmas_carol.txt) and their frequency, i.e. how many times each word appears in the file.

Thanks,"

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class Practice {


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> dup = new ArrayList<String>();

        File file = new File ("christmas_carol.txt");

        try {

        String line = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        String[] lines = line.split(" ");


        for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i ++) {
            array.add(lines[i]);
            //System.out.println(lines[i]); //printing the contents of the file.
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < dup.size(); i ++){
            dup.add(line);
            if (dup.equals(lines)) {
                dup.remove(i);
                System.out.print(i);
            }
        }


        } catch (IOException ie) {
            System.err.print("No Such File Found!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Believe me it is not! It is just an old practice...

Comment: If it's for "practice", shouldn't you have something to show?

Comment: Frankly, we don't care much whether or not it's a homework.  We judge questions the same way

Comment: You mean an answer... Sure I'll share

Comment: @Whizz No, we mean what you've tried.

Comment: There are some thing that we'd like to know, such as the _content of the file_.

Comment: Got it... I posted what I got...

Comment: if you un-comment `//System.out.println(lines[i]); //printing the contents of the file.` what happens?

Comment: Okay... So I'm confused with how to check for duplicates? #Number2

Comment: @Whizz Does that mean that we can delete number 1 from your question?

Comment: `if (dup.equals(lines)) {` is never going to be true.  You're comparing an `ArrayList<String>` to a `String[]`

Comment: @samIam, Check my code... see if I got it right. If so, then yeah will omit

Comment: Also, you're taking in all the lines. Good start. Nowhere are you taking any of the words.

Comment: @azurefrog... Yes! Here where I'm stuck!

Comment: @AntonH... What do you mean? I'm just printing the result on the console... I'm not writing to any file

Comment: @samIam it will print the contents of the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer explained in comments

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


public class Practice {


    public static void main (String[] args) {

//      ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
//      ArrayList<String> dup = new ArrayList<String>();

    File file = new File ("christmas_carol.txt");
    try {

        String fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        String[] lines = fileContent.split(" ");

//          You need not iterate and add instead you can use Arrays.asList. But if its for an exercise this loop is fine. 
//          for (int i = 0 ; i < lines.length; i ++) {
//              array.add(lines[i]);
//          }
//          
//          But better to use for-each loop as
//          for(String line : lines){
//              array.add(line);
//          }

        List<String> array = Arrays.asList(lines);

//          The easiest way to avoid duplicate is to use java.util.Set
        Set<String> uniqueWords = new HashSet<String>(array);

//          But if you want to iterate this logic is wrong. Firstly the dup list is just initialized and empty. So the size is zero and it'll never enter the loop.
//          Secondly dup.equals(lines) is comparing an arraylist with array. That'll always be false
//          for (int i = 0 ; i < dup.size(); i ++){
//              dup.add(line);
//              if (dup.equals(lines)) {
//                  dup.remove(i);
//                  System.out.print(i);
//              }
//          }
//          
//          So what you need here is again a simple loop
        List<String> dup = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String line : array){
            if(!dup.contains(line)){
                dup.add(line);
            }
        }

//          To find frequency of a word the easiest way is to use a map which keep the word and its count. So when we encounter a duplicate just update the count.
        Map<String, Integer> wordFrequency = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        int count;
        for(String line : array){
            count = 0;
            if(wordFrequency.containsKey(line)){
                count = wordFrequency.get(line);
            }
            wordFrequency.put(line, ++count);
        }

    } catch (IOException ie) {
        System.err.print("No Such File Found!");
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any other way besides using Set?

Comment: Yes. Using the loop. I mentioned that way too below in comment.. "So what you need here is again a simple loop" :)